# MySQL Multiple Column Unique Key

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm familiar with the syntax of 
`create unique index 'blah' on 'some_table' ('col1','col2')` 
however I'm unsure exactly how this will behave. More specifically, the documentation says

> [A column list of the form (col1,col2,...) creates a multiple-column index. Index values are formed by concatenating the values of the given columns.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

That seems like it might be okay in some cases, but I want make a table that holds just numbers unique. So, I could see col1 being 12 and col2 being 2, which will concatenate to 122 from what I can tell, and then a value of col1 1 and col2 22 would match that, which is not what I want. Is there a way to define a separator for the concatenation or is there already one in place? Should I be doing this differently?

Here's an attempt at a diagram

```
table 1             middle               table 2
-------             ------               -------
t1_id               mid_id               t2_id
some_value          t1_id                another_value
                    t2_id
```

I want the t1_id and t2_id combination to be unique, but t1 can repeat and t2 can repeat.

Comment: Have you looked at INFORMATION_SCHEMA to see what your index looks like?

Comment: I haven't actually implemented the above design because I'm not sure that it would work. I could give it a try real quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible nor necessary to specify a separator. The index works as you want it to.